# Error on PHP when upload file (WebKitFormBoundary)

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm working with **[FileUpload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)** to provide better support for user uploads. When I upload a ZIP file (~8Mb), the PHP script is throwing this error:

```
"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryJOPvhJX0UqLwCUte"
```

I looked for it on Google, but didn't find anything clear. Can someone explain me what does it mean, and what can I do?

ZIP file content:

- DAE file
- Folder with texture images

Comment: That message isn't an error message - it's part of the structure of the uploaded data, delimiting the different parts of the upload. You might check the maximum size of upload permitted by PHP - but that's just a guess. Is there any more to the message?

Comment: No, the script is dealing with it like an error. I've just contacted with my host provider to get more info about this. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

Comment this line out, or delete it:

```
xhr_object.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: I just spent 3 hours fighting with this issue. Thanks for this.